# html/css to fit entire screen for mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use css to fit my form/background image to take up to ENTIRE screen, right now the background image is cut off on the bottom and the form isn't fully taking up all the spaces on the screen instead there are white spaces on the bottom and on the top of the screen. 
[image]

Here's the entire code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>SpaceMX</title>
  <!-- CORE CSS-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
    height: 100%;

}
html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;

}
body {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.margin {
  margin: 0 !important;

}
form{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qhn5HDG.png');
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>

</head>

<body class="">



      <form class="login-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12 center">
            <p class="center login-form-text" class="responsive-img valign profile-image-login">SpaceMX</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
            <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="username" class="center-align">Username</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-communication-email prefix"></i>
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
            <label for="email" class="center-align">Email</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
            <input id="password-again" type="password">
            <label for="password-again">Re-type password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <a href="register.html" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12">Register Now</a>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <p class="margin center medium-small sign-up" color="white">Already have an account? <a href="login.html">Login</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>





  <!-- ================================================
    Scripts
    ================================================ -->

  <!-- jQuery Library -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--materialize js-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-27820211-3', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use vh, vw instead of precents for sizing !

Comment: That didn't do anything but made by background image even smaller and wierder and it still has white spaces on top and bottom of the page. I changed all the % to vh for height and vw for width,

Comment: absolute the form position with top, left 0px, and maybe your browser doesnt support vh, vw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the display: table from the html tag and display: table-cell from the body tag in css. the body centers in the html tag because of that, which creates the whitespace on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Change css to this:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

form{
  position absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qhn5HDG.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers has their own default padding and margin. So you have to make them equal to zero.

```
form{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qhn5HDG.png');
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Please tell me if this is what you wanted or not.